# Angular 2 - Chrome freeze issue with angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I am facing a strange issue with my angular 2 application, on some of my users machine the application just freezes and chrome becomes unresponsive specifically during http post with file data in the form body. Can someone help understand the reason for this or any tools that which i run to debug the issue? I have noticed that this happens on google chrome running on windows 7 machines.